# How to handle table headings in nextjs using json file?

Tags: javascript, next.js

I have a .json file with entries which I listed in a table. Now I do only want to display some of the headings and not all depending on some checkbox or similar (ie useState).

Packliste.js

```
import Table from "../components/Table";
import data from "../data.json";


function Packliste() {
  const getHeadings = () => {
    return Object.keys(data[0]);
  };

  return (
    
     
      <div className="container">
        <Table theadData={getHeadings()} tbodyData={data} />
      </div>
      
   
  );
}
export default Packliste;
```

Table.js

```
export default function Table({ theadData, tbodyData }) {
  return (
    <table>
      <thead>
        <tr>
          {theadData.map((heading) => {
            return <th key={heading}>{heading}</th>;
          })}
        </tr>
      </thead>

      <tbody>
        {tbodyData.map((row, index) => {
          return (
            <tr key={index}>
              {theadData.map((key, index) => {
                return <td key={row[key]}>{row[key]}</td>;
              })}
            </tr>
          );
        })}
      </tbody>
    </table>
  );
}
```

I tried to change the props of the Table.js function.

Comment: Do you have the code for the checkboxes? You could create an array and based on which is checked add or remove from that array. then .filter the headings based on that array of checkboxes.